# How to remove trailing spaces in a file and merge with previous line?

Tags: shell, unix, merge

I have a text file whose conntents are this:

```
Fri Oct 02 19:52:02 +0000 2009 | JeLLz Mamii;) | DopeAssDarLey | my b.iâ¥ BITCH!! | @_steffhoney lmfao oh Dayum gull inee hihup Walmart en boiy maself sum skoo sepplies

Tue Aug 30 23:29:47 +0000 2011 | Braydon Tyrrell | braydon_tyrrell | westlock. AB. canada | RT @Darkskin: RT @JazmineDukes: @Darkskin Who are you that U have a blue check mark by ur name?? &lt; 
I polish shoes at Walmart while pp ...
```

As can be seen the line 'I polish shoes..' is a part of the second record of `Tues Aug 30`. But while processing this file for something, it is taken as a third entirely different record.

I want to be able to merge the 'I polish shoes' line with the line just before it, i.e 'check mark by your name??' Is there a way to do this. This anomaly is present in many of the records in the file. So I need to be able to do it for all such records, so that my output looks something like

```
Fri Oct 02 19:52:02 +0000 2009 | JeLLz Mamii;) | DopeAssDarLey | my b.iâ¥ BITCH!! | @_steffhoney lmfao oh Dayum gull inee hihup Walmart en boiy maself sum skoo sepplies

Tue Aug 30 23:29:47 +0000 2011 | Braydon Tyrrell | braydon_tyrrell | westlock. AB. canada | RT @Darkskin: RT @JazmineDukes: @Darkskin Who are you that U have a blue check mark by ur name?? &lt; I polish shoes at Walmart while pp ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This will join the next line if it contains a trailing space:

```
sed '/ $/ N; s/\n//' file.txt
```

If however there could be multiple lines with trailing spaces, you'll need a loop:

```
sed -e :a -e '/ $/ { $!N; s/\n//; ta }' file
```

Results:

```
Fri Oct 02 19:52:02 +0000 2009 | JeLLz Mamii;) | DopeAssDarLey | my b.iâ¥ BITCH!! | @_steffhoney lmfao oh Dayum gull inee hihup Walmart en boiy maself sum skoo sepplies

Tue Aug 30 23:29:47 +0000 2011 | Braydon Tyrrell | braydon_tyrrell | westlock. AB. canada | RT @Darkskin: RT @JazmineDukes: @Darkskin Who are you that U have a blue check mark by ur name?? &lt; I polish shoes at Walmart while pp ...
```

Comment: The looping solution is pretty smart (+1).

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
awk -v RS='\n\n+' '{ sub(/\n/, "", $0) ; print $0 "\n" }' log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -00 -lpe 's/\n//g'
```

That reads the file a "paragraph" at a time, and removes "interior" newlines.